# Why does electron refresh my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron

At the moment I am trying to implement tabs in Electron using jQuery. To do this I have a navbar at the top with text buttons that when clicked hide all other divs and show the one div.

```
$("#home").show();
$("#tasks").hide();

$("#tasksButton").click(function(){
        $("#home").hide();
        $("#tasks").show();
    });
```

This works for a split second, but then the window goes back to the original state where home div is shown and tasks div is hidden. 
I tried to test what could be causing this by putting console outputs at the start of the script, at the start of the function, and at the end. These would show as expected but then the console would clear and it would just show the one at the start of the script.

This proves to me that the issue is Electron restarting my script, and I have no clue how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: My bet is tasksButton is a submit button.

Comment: As per @epascarello's comment, in your function callback to `$("#tasksButton").click()`, add an `event` argument and do `event.preventDefault()` before you toggle the `#home` and `#tasks`. Try that.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was because tasksButton was a link so it was trying to load a link, thus refreshing the page.